# Tampermonkey run script every 10s

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I'm trying to build a script that runs every 10seconds and sends a GM_notification. But I dont receive any notification. What's wrong?

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        _Notification test
// @grant       GM_notification
// @require     http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

setTimeout(function() {

GM_notification ( {title: 'foo', text: '42'} );

}, 1000);
```

Comment: this script will run once after 1sec

Comment: Does this answer your question? [setTimeout or setInterval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729921/settimeout-or-setinterval)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need `match` `url` give url of page and for every `10` sec need `setInterval` not `setTimeout`

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        _Notification test
// @match       https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70249774/tampermonkey-run-script-every-10s*
// @grant       GM_notification
// @require     http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js
// ==/UserScript==




var intervalId = window.setInterval(function(){
  GM_notification ( {
    title: 'foo', text: '42'
} );
}, 10000);
```

Comment: I added `image` parameter but still it doesnt show. 
If i add // @match       https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70249774/*
the notification will appear when I will navigate to this page

Comment: @rowend i have update my answer now it is working